# How to prove the following equation has only one solution?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have a equation like this:

$$
f(t)=-2ae^{-2at}+2ae^{-at}-2be^{-2bt}
$$
where $0<a<b$.

I wish to show that the function $f(t)$ has only one root for $t>0$. Clearly, when $t=0$, $f(0)=-2b<0$, and 
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=0.
$$
But how may I prove that there exists $t_0>0$, such that $f(t)>0$ if $t>t_0$ and $f(t)<0$, $t<t_0$?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a typo ? I think the last summand should be $2be^{-2b\color{red}t}$

Comment: @callculus Thx! corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation $f(t)=0$ is the same as $g(t)=\exp(2bt)f(t)=0$. Now you can compute the derivative of $g$, if I am not wrong $g^{\prime}(t)$ is  $2a\exp((2b-a)t)((2b-a)-2(b-a)\exp(-at))$, hence $>0$ on $[0,+\infty[$ (as $2b-a>2b-2a$ and $1\geq \exp(-at)$). So $g$ is strictly increasing, $g(0)=-2b<0$, $g(t)\to +\infty$ if $t\to +\infty$, we are done.

Comment: This looks right to me, but you might want to explain in a little more detail why $g^{\prime}(t)>0$ for $t>0$.

Comment: @user84413, Ok, Thank you, I have edited my answer.